# Bash expansion to list from a directory

Tags: bash, shell, tab-completion

I tend to work on multiple projects, all stored inside my home (~) directory inside a directory called `web`.

At one point all my projects were inside a single directory inside this; so to move from project a to project b:

```
~ $ cd ../project-b
```

However now I've started to categorise projects, meaning I'd then have to enter

```
~ $ cd ~/web/project-name
```

I'd like to write either a shell script or alias such that I can type

```
~ $ command project-name
```

And switch to it, with tab completion such that `proj` in the above could be tab completed to `project-`. The projects could be defined as a file within `~/web`, with a fallback to any direct child of that directory.

The whole realm of tab completion is out of my knowledge area really - if this seems trivial and my best bet would be to read more on tab completion please could you comment with a concise online resource and I can try my own solution. Of course full script solutions are also more than welcome, as are features of the shell that I've completely missed!

Comment: Setting `CDPATH=.:~/web` will get you halfway there: from anywhere you can `cd project-name` No tab completion though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a symbolic link to the directory you want to quickly navigate to:

```
ln -s ~/web/project-b ~/web/project-name ~
```

This is a lot simpler than implementing a shell script plus a custom Bash completion script.

Another easy solution you can use without implementing anything is to search through your Bash history: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> starts a substring search, and by the time you've entered <kbd>project-name</kbd> it has probably already found the entry. If not, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> again searches for the next older history entry with the same substring. With a simple [configuration tweak](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/e6f56a69cfa33d82c21b8fc2d97a6b804e6c835e/.inputrc#L1-L3) you can also simply type <kbd>cd</kbd> and press <kbd>Up</kbd> to go to earlier commands starting with "cd".

Comment: Both of those seem to work to an extent, interested to explore the search option and whether I'd be able to avoid relative directory `cd` commands which would likely pollute the history if I was in a directory with a different relative path.

Comment: If you make sure to generally use an absolute path or one anchored at `~` you shouldn't have any problems with this.